# Modules in which its torsion submodule is a direct summand

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative domain.

For every $A$-mod $M$ we can define its torsion submodule as $T(M)=\{m\in M \mid \exists a\in A\setminus \{0\} \text{ such that } am=0 \}$. Hence we have an exact sequence

$$0\rightarrow T(M) \rightarrow M \rightarrow M/T(M)\rightarrow 0$$

Where the last term is torsion free. This sequence split iff $T(M)$ is a direct summand of $M$ and in that case we can write $M$ as the direct sum of a torsion module with a torsion-free module.

This happens for example when $A$ is a PID and $M$ is finitely generated by the structure theorem that we have in this case. Also this happens trivially when $A$ is a field.

My questions are

> Is there an example of a sequence that doesn't split in the case that $A$ is PID and $M$ is not finitely generated?

and

> Is there known any other "big family" of module for which this exact sequence split?

Comment: How about the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$ which has torsion module $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$?  (Not sure if it actually works as an example...)

Comment: $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ is injective so the sequence must split, though I can't come up with the splitting map at the moment.

Comment: Doesn't [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10007/the-torsion-submodule-of-prod-mathbbz-p-is-not-a-direct-summand-of-prod?rq=1) answer the first question? Everything there is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Comment: @AndrewKelley ooh it's a nice example, I think that's a good answer for my first question.

Comment: Regarding your second question: It seems that [this article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01431462) (which refers to Kaplansky, Irving 1960) suggests that the sequence splits for all fin. gen. $M$ if and only if $A$ is a Prüfer domain.

Comment: @Bubaya that's such an interesting article, it addresses exactly this question! Thank you for sharing it.